# How to discover and connect an IP camera to UWP

Tags: uwp

I need to connect IP cameras to a UWP app I am busy with, I have been able to do this using WPF and Ozeki, but cannot seem to figure it out using UWP, Looks like it does not support Ozeki
and the Microsoft documentation is making my head hurt, can anyone please give me some pointers and or example?

Thanks

Comment: Thank You, I can get a webcam to work, it is relatively easy to do so, my problem is to discover and display an IP camera. the documentation you refer to is the documents I have been reading to no avail, I am new to this so possibly not understanding it

Comment: Hi, You can ask OZEKI's customer service staff, the use of a webcam in UWP is through the method I provide, but this may vary depending on the device

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a webcam, you need to first add the capability of `webcam` to the `package.appxmanifest` in the UWP project.

```xml
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
```

---

For how to use the camera in the UWP project, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access).

Thanks